# DNS configuration for webserver path

Tags: domain-name-system, nginx, domain, apache-2.4, linux-vserver

What I have is: some vservers and some domains, located at different hosters. A webserver with Port 8081 on one server. I have a path like "123.123.123.123:8081/app/"

What I want is: a subdomain pointing to this path. For example: app.mydoman.com. I tried it at some ways, but I´m not happy with the only solution I found: a redirection over a meta tag in html. It works but I am sure you can show me a better way to do that.

Thank your very much !

Comment: DNS can't be used to point to a "path".

Comment: is there any possibility to get what i want? then without DNS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several choices:

1. Have your Apache server with a VirtualHost listening for app.mydomain.com, and use mod_proxy to fetch the content from the app server and show it.
2. Change DNS for app.mydomain.com to point to your app server set it to serve from /app by default. Use a firewall or NAT device to redirect port 80 connections to port 8081 internally.
3. Keep doing what you are doing, but using a HTTP redirect instead of a HTML meta refresh tag, so it happens earlier/lower in the stack.